# Weird behaviour with the TypedPropertyDecorator Generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-decorator

I was trying to create a strongly-typed decorator in TypeScript (4.9.5), when I noticed a really strange behaviour. I was able to create a minimal reproduction of it on TypeScript Playground (link below). Here is the code snippet:

```js
type Message = { Body: string };
type Test = (message: Message) => Promise<void | Message>;

// This works as it should no complaints that this function does not respect Test type
const test: Test = async (message: Message) => ({ Body: 'hey' });

const a = (target: object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<Test>) => {
    const og = descriptor.value;
    console.log('Hey')
};

class A {
    @a
    // ^ This does not work as expected it's complaining that the function
    // return type is not exactly Promise<void | Message>
    public async method(message: Message): Promise<Message> {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Why is the decorator in this example throwing an error when the return type is within the union provided? And is there a way to fix this?

[reprod](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeKBvKAhA9gCYgBcU8wATgJYB2KUAvgNwBQokUAKgsFJgAoAtgmRoycRKggBKfgD4oABUr4h1eBAA8AN3zVCUAD6xR0+W1YB6K9wAWGqAHd8lANbwoST9T7w7+ACuADaErADG+LQUUMC8ZDwxmN4gtOFQwmbiplJocuiKAjgExGQA5HYQIGVMMpaR0XxI-BnASJRowGT4AEYAVhDhwAA0UGCqkJSgANJVZBQ09MbkIEI9+MGjhAjhNGDArgngEIQq+JOgACI7eweUWonA8vmKWKxQH1ANMfgMmNvwXbUfauAB0OiQwUCEDYny+UXgGwgoOCvwEZQAElUyjJWCxWBFgt5PABBbDvT42eyOQj4BBQWj4YAUj4AASQLLGgR6wWo6RSaSgImAAUImVyEAkWVk5LhcMoEGAgUotCF0thn0YeKAA)

I expected since the method that is being decorated has matching arguments and a return type that respects the `Promise<void | Message>` union that it would be allowed to use this decorator without TypeScript complaining.

In my snippet we can see that outside the `TypedDecoratorProperty` this works as expected but not when passed into the generic. It complains about the `set` method within the type but I don't see an obvious reason that I am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little look and it seems that attr has to return the extact type of `TypedPropertyDescriptor`

And Method `method` return Message and there is not posibility for it to return `void` that is why it complain.

Try adding

```
   @a
    public async method(message: Message) {
        return message as void | Message;
    }
```

Should remove the error.

I would rather use `TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>` instead

Comment: To get around the `any`, you can also define `const a = <T extends unknown>(target: object, propertyKey: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>) => {`

Comment: Hmm I wanted something that was type-safe and intuitive to use because I was planning to make this decorator accessible to other colleagues of mine and I didn't want them to use it incorrectly since only a specific type of method works on this decorator. I guess it's really either I cast the return type or I let anything use this decorator and I vet the typing within the decorator function itself..